# Symfony - fallback to another application if Symfonfy app can not handle the request

Tags: yii, symfony

We have an old Yii application along with new Symfony one.

The basic idea is simple - I need to check if there is a route matching in Symfony application then it is cool, if not then bootstrap Yii application and try to handle the request with it.

The main idea to not instantiate AppKernel (and do not load autoload.php - since there is two different autoload.php for each project) before I am sure there is route matching.
Can I do it somehow?

Comment: I would search by server configuration. Trying to give the request to symfony and if symfony returns 404, trying to give it to Yii.

Comment: If my answer is satisfactory, please select it as best answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We've done this before with legacy applications.

There are two approaches you can take.

1. Wrap your old application inside a symfony project (recommended).

Unfortunately this will indeed load the symfony front-controller and kernel. No way around that. You need to make sure that symfony *can't* handle the request and to do that the kernel needs to be booted up.

2. Use sub-directories and apache virtual hosts to load one application vs the other as needed.

Given option 1,

You can either create your own front controller that loads either symfony or yii by reading routes (from static files if using yml or xml, or annotations which will be more complex) OR EventListener (RequestListener) that listens to the HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST and ensures that a route can be returned.

**Creating your own front controller is the only way that you can make it not load the symfony kernel, but it will require you to write something that understands the routes in both frameworks (or at least symfony's) and hands off the request appropriately.**

Event listener example:

```
public function onkernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
        return;
    }

    ... Code to continue normally, or bootstrap yii and return a custom response... (Can include and ob_start, or make an http request, etc)
}

public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest']
    ];
}
```

As you see, the kernel needs to be booted to ensure symfony can't serve the route. Unless creating your own front controller (as stated above).

A third approach would be to create a fallback controller, which would load up a specified URL if no route was found within symfony. Although this approach is generally used for legacy projects that lack a framework and use page scripts instead of proper routes, and definitely requires the use/help of output buffering.

The EventListener approach gives you the opportunity to create a proper Request to hand off to yii, and using what is returned to create a Response as proper symfony object (can also use ob or other options).

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if I can find out whether symfony is able to handle the request without booting the kernel

Comment: and also, in case I booted Yii, how properly to stop the Symfony app ?

Comment: I updated the answer to properly clarify. You wouldn't stop the symfony app if you listen to the request. You could however create your own front controller although that would require some work to read routes.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative to vpassapera's solution -http://stovepipe.systems/post/migrating-your-project-to-symfony

Comment: as author of this post, I agree ;)

Comment: I also mentioned using a fallback controller :) (Covered under 3rd approach above)

But a fallback controller still loads symfony first.